# F# работа с WinForms

Tags: winforms, f#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работать в F# с OpenFileDialog. Скажем, чтобы при нажатии кнопки вылезало диалоговое окно

Comment: Собственно, так же как в C#. Что именно не получается?

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.Click.Add(fun _ -> let dialog = new OpenFileDialog()
  if dialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK then printfn dialog.FileName)
```